# Dart editor run error "could not start pub serve or connect to pub" on it's sample web application project

Tags: dart, dart-editor, dart-pub

I just installed Dart Editor and created a simple web application and when I click on run it shows this error and nothing happens.

"could not start pub serve or connect to pub"

How is the configuration of dart editor for Windows7 sp1 64bit?
What am I supposed to do to run the sample project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a common problem

- http://dartbug.com/20771 (mentions that an internet connection is necessary)
- http://dartbug.com/19659
- http://dartbug.com/19847
- http://dartbug.com/19656 (it was mentioned that reinstall Dart helped)

Nothing contains a good solution.

For weird problems it's always worth to try `pub cache repair` on the command line.

Comment: I'm using Dart editor version 1.6.0. It's portable and doesn't have any installation process and just by running exe file it starts up.
So I don't know what you mean by re-installation.

Comment: I didn't have the problem myself. It was just reported by someone in the discussion of the linked bug that this solved the problem. I had problems (of a different kind) several times after downloading and extracting an archive file for a Dart update. Downloading again and extracting solved it. This issue was reported several times but no real cause is known or solution available yet.

Comment: Vielen Dank mein frund.

Comment: Could you fix it? How?

Comment: No. not yet. I'm still try to fix it. Still searching on the net. Seem's some installation requires for dart editor but mine starts without any installation. I don't know for now what to do